# Spam email sent to my contacts pretending to be me.

Tags: email, spam

I just found out someone has been sending spam emails to my contacts.
I first thought that my account was hacked, but the emails aren't coming from my account but from a weird email address (my name followed by @deanglyn.freeserve.co.uk). That's really annoying as most of my contacts are work related.

Does this mean that my email account has been hacked or that someone just got access to my contact list? I'm wondering because if my account was hacked, why use a weird email address?

What do you think I should do?

Thanks.

Comment: You probably answered it yourself. If someone had access to your email account, that person would most likely use the associated address for maximum efficiency. He/She probably got hold of your contact list. Or maybe it is even someone in your social circle holding a grudge against you or someone else. Without more details, it's hard to tell :)

Comment: Question is, how many of your contacts received the fake message? Everyone from your email account's list? It's an interesting question so please provide some more information :)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at it in the wrong way. One of the following scenarios is probably happened:

- The attacker gained your contact list and used their email to spam your contact list - In this case I suggest you look over apps/programs that are installed on the device you use for checking your email.
- Attacker has hacked your email account and stole your contacts and then spammed them using their own email so your email provider wont block them (They might connect through an API or try sending all kinds of spam that your email provider might have blocked) - In this case I suggest you change your password and keep alert for any suspicious activity (You might want to check how they managed to hack you)

I also suggest you use [haveibeenpwned](http://haveibeenpwned.com) this website to see if you were hacked.